# How to import modules regardless of the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I would like to know if there is any way to be able to use the modules of a project, regardless of the module's path, if it is in one or more directories above the current script

since what I have tried to do is something like this but it doesn't work.

```
import os

r = os.path.realpath(file.py)

from r import functionR
```

When I investigated a little more, I found something that talks about adding the modules to the main path, but I don't know if that is correct?

I hope you can help me a little

added an example route i'm using

```
root
    folder1
        folder11
            file1.py
    folder2
        folder22
            file2.py
    file_one.py
```

For example, try using the file_one.py module in files that are at lower levels, for example file1.py or file2.py

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding the directory containing the modules of interest to the sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([put_directory_here])
```

or add the directory to the PATH environment variable

or add the folder containing the modules to a location that is already in the path i.e. site packages

this way python knows where to look for the modules and they will be accessible anywhere

there's also a ton of info about absolute/relative imports of modules here: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: ,This would have to put in each file.py

and to use it I would only do a common import for example from my_file import my_function